# parfor loop showing no significant speedup compared to for loop

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm trying to run this regression loop as a parfor-loop:

```
load dataq.mat % load 'A_Data' and 'A_ref' matrix

k=length(A_ref);
theta=zeros(k,5); % preallocation
b_ref=zeros(k,1);

poolobj = parpool(8);
parfor i=1:k % regression

  W = sqrt( ...
    exp( ...
    -( ...
    ( ( A_Data(:,2)-A_ref(i,2) ) / 0.6 ).^2+ ...
    ( ( A_Data(:,3)-A_ref(i,3) ) / 0.6 ).^2+ ...
    ( ( A_Data(:,4)-A_ref(i,4) ) / 0.6 ).^2+ ...
    ( ( A_Data(:,5)-A_ref(i,5) ) / 0.6 ).^2 ...
    ) /2 ...
    ) ...
    );

 theta(i,:)=regress(W.*b_Data,repmat(W,1,5).*A_Data);
 b_ref(i,1)=A_ref(i,:)*theta(i,:)';

end
delete(poolobj);
```

It goes well without error, but It shows no significant speed boost compared to for loop.

And I got this warning message:

> "the entire array ('A_Data' , 'A_ref') is a broadcast variable. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead."

How can I deal with this problem?

Note that:
A_Data: 1710203x5 double,
A_ref: 5760x5 double

Comment: Parfor loops are useful when each iteration is independent of other iterations, so that the loop only needs to access the row or column that is given by the loop index https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/419074-parfor-loop-the-entire-array-or-structure-h-is-a-broadcast-variable-this-might-result-in-unnecess

Comment: Note that `parfor` was designed to spread computations across compute nodes in a cluster. This is not a shared-memory parallelism. `parfor` will start up multiple MATLAB sessions, and transfer data between them. This is efficient only if the amount of computation in each loop iteration is large. It is possible nowadays to configure the Parallel Computing Toolbox to use threads instead of separate MATLAB processes, try `parpool('threads')`.

Comment: See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html#mw_6bbf0761-74c0-404e-9db6-77b82c7c138c) to learn what you can and cannot do in a thread-based parallel session.

Comment: Another side note, the multiple calculations with `A_Data` and `A_ref` is unnecessary. You can shorten it down to: `sqrt(exp(-sum(((A_data(:,2:5)-A_ref(i,2:5))/0.6).^2,1)))`. You might get a minor speed increase from `A_data(:,2:5)-A_ref(i,2:5)`, though it makes the code harder to read.